# How to keep session alive using jQuery or javascript

Tags: jquery, session-timeout

I have a simple aspx page called `keepAlive.aspx`. I need to call this page using jQuery or similar every 2 minutes to make sure that session is alive.

Could someone help me with script to call this page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshSession() {
    var a = window.open("keepAlive.aspx", '_blank');
    a.focus();
    a.close();
}
var milliseconds = 10000 //whatever you want here...
window.setInterval("refreshSession", milliseconds);
```

this will open a new window, make a request and close it. Use with a timer to keep sessions alive.

Comment: don't think i can specify period with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make an ajax request in the background. It will keep up the session.